# Xcode shows compile-time warnings, will it be rejected if I submit it to the App Store?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store, warnings

Xcode shows compile-time warnings; will my app be rejected if I submit it to the App Store?

I have a warning that I cannot solve, and I'm wondering if Apple can reject the application because of this.

the warning is:

unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Perhaps posting the warning would be useful, Mr Caraza?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no evidence of a warning encoded into the final `.ipa` file.

However, for your own peace of mind, it's best to find a way to solve the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Your app will not be rejected *because* it has a warning at compile time. Apple will not be aware of this fact.

However, if this warning results in a crash or performance issue with your app, then it will be rejected on that basis.